# Renaming SQLite Tables/Columns/Rows after indices have been created

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design, format

If I rename SQLite Tables/Columns/Rows after indices have been created, will the old indices still be functional?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `ALTER TABLE` with `RENAME TO` to rename a **table**, then as described on [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) (from the sqlite docs) the indices will still work:

> The ALTER TABLE command in SQLite allows the user to rename a table [...] If the table being renamed has triggers or indices, then these remain attached to the table after it has been renamed.

But note there's no renaming of **columns** allowed. This is one of the [SQL features not implemented by sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html):

> Only the RENAME TABLE and ADD COLUMN variants of the ALTER TABLE command are supported. Other kinds of ALTER TABLE operations such as DROP COLUMN, ALTER COLUMN, ADD CONSTRAINT, and so forth are omitted.

**Rows** don't have names (except in the sense of having a PK) so there's not really a way of renaming them.

Comment: Is there a way to copy over the information from one column to another, and then delete the first column?

Comment: See this [other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805363/how-do-i-rename-a-column-in-a-sqlite-database-table) on renaming columns

Comment: I was actually just looking through that :).  The first answer looks great, but how should I deal with the indices?

Comment: I think you need to recreate them manually. The [sql FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) has instructions on how you can get a list of the existing indices before you start the process.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using Rails ActiveRecord migrations to maintain your database. This can be done outside of Rails. So you app doesn't need to be a Rails app to use rake tasks

See here for an excellent blog on how to do this http://exposinggotchas.blogspot.com/2011/02/activerecord-migrations-without-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the old indices will still be functional.

Be aware, that sqlite doesn't care about the names for the indexes. Initially when an index is created usually they are named after the table and field, so when you rename the table, the indexes will still have the name of the old table in it. This can cause problems, when you for example:

- dump the table
- rename the old table:

  ```
  sqlite3 "$DB" "PRAGMA busy_timeout=20000; ALTER TABLE '$TABLE' RENAME TO '$TABLE"_backup"'"
  ```
- reimport the dumped table

This will cause an error, that the **indexes already exist**.

Solution: Rename the indexes too, or delete them in the renamed table before you reimport the original  (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41577393/1069083)).