# SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: User_id: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "User_id" integer/

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I ran the command

`rails g migration AddUser_idToComments User_id:string`

and then I figured out that User_id should be an integer and so I ran

`rails g migration AddUser_idToComments User_id:integer --force` thinking that it would overwrite the initial command.

But now, I'm getting this error:

```
louismorin$ rake db:migrate
== 20140910155248 AddIndexToComments: migrating ===============================
-- add_column(:comments, :Index, :string)
   -> 0.0069s
== 20140910155248 AddIndexToComments: migrated (0.0070s) ======================

== 20140910181022 AddUserIdToComments: migrating ==============================
-- add_column(:comments, :User_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: User_id: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "User_id" integer/Users/louismorin/code/CP299/db/migrate/20140910181022_add_user_id_to_comments.rb:3:in `change'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: User_id: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "User_id" integer
/Users/louismorin/code/CP299/db/migrate/20140910181022_add_user_id_to_comments.rb:3:in`change'
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: User_id
/Users/louismorin/code/CP299/db/migrate/20140910181022_add_user_id_to_comments.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here's my schema.rb file

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140910155210) do

```
create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "body"
  t.integer  "post_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "User_Id"
end

add_index "comments", ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id"

create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "topic_id"
end

add_index "posts", ["topic_id"], name: "index_posts_on_topic_id"
add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"

create_table "topics", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.boolean  "public",      default: true
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "confirmation_token"
  t.datetime "confirmed_at"
  t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
  t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "role"
  t.string   "avatar"
  t.string   "Image"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique:     true

end
```

```

Comment: SQLite does not directly support changing a column's type.

Comment: Louis -- can you add your `db/schema.rb` file above? It'd be helpful to see what your database looks like currently.

Comment: Yeah. The mixed CamelCase_snake_case migration name seems to have confused Rails, resulting in that upper-cased column name `User_id`. Just a thing to remember. Have you tried the below?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the error, your second migration -- changing the column type -- didn't run. If that migration was only intended to change that one column, we could then delete the file it generated and try again.

If you don't yet have any data in that column that you care about, that's pretty easy:

`rails g migration ChangeTypeOfUserIdOnComments`

> This migration name isn't special. Might as well have been `DoWhateverIWant`

Then, edit the created migration's change method to something like this:

```
def change
  remove_column :comments, :user_id
  add_column :comments, :user_id, :integer
  add_index :comments, :user_id
end
```

When you then run your un-run migrations `rake db:migrate`, it shouldn't trip up on the one which errored (because we deleted it), and then it should run this one, which removes the column and adds it back with the correct type.

If you DO have data you want to save, the procedure is more complicated. Your change method would have to grab the current user_id's for each comment, and then assign them to the new comments when we create the new column. The below should hopefully work:

```
def change
  user_ids = {}
  Comment.find_each{ |c| user_ids[c.id] = c.user_id.to_i } 

  remove_column :comments, :user_id
  add_column :comments, :user_id, :integer
  add_index :comments, :user_id
  Comment.each{ |c| c.update_attribute(:user_id, user_ids[c.id])
end
```

Also note that the names of the migration in the command are generally all CamelCase or all snake_case. So: `AddColumnUserIdToComments` or `add_column_user_id_to_comments`. Naming as you did might cause problems.

** EDIT **

[Modify a Column's Type in sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083543/modify-a-columns-type-in-sqlite3)

It appears that SQLite has NO good way to modify/drop a column. I'd suggest either:

#### Dropping and restarting a SQLITe table

Drop the table, drop the original user_id migration and the line in the new one about removing the old user_id column, and then create a new table with the new migrations. Should work fine if you don't care about your data

#### Switching to Postgres, which is the database Heroku uses.

It's probably a good idea (because you want your production and local databases to behave identically), but can be bug-prone to switch to.

Look here for guidance -- [Change from SQLite to PostgreSQL in a fresh Rails project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710654/how-do-you-easily-change-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-in-rails)

Comment: I tried the def change method suggested. I don't care about the data. This is the error that I'm getting now...173-230-187-53:cp299 louismorin$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError: Multiple migrations have the name AddUserIdToComments

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: Sounds like you have two migrations by that name :). The second failing one won't have been run, so deleting it shouldn't mess with migration history. I'd just delete the second one (ordered by timestamp), and try again.

Comment: I removed the second migration, and now I'm back to the same error as before
```
173-230-187-53:cp299 louismorin$ rake db:migrate
== 20140910190321 ChangeTypeOfUserIdOnComments: migrating =====================
-- remove_column(:comments, :user_id)
   -> 0.0180s
-- add_column(:comments, :user_id, :integer)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "user_id" integer/Users/louismorin/code/CP299/db/migrate/20140910190321_change_type_of_user_id_on_comments.rb:4:..
```

Comment: Updated my answer -- seems like SQLite is even more rigid than I thought.

Comment: Hi Sasha, I downloaded http://sqlitestudio.pl/ and I dropped the table. When I looked through the comments table Index and User_Id were there... when I run rake db:migrate I get this error

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: user_id: ALTER TABLE "comments" ADD "user_id" integer/Users/louismorin/code/CP299/db/migrate/20140910190321_change_type_of_user_id_on_comments.rb:4:in `change'

Comment: Do you have a link to your repo? I'm not sure why that would be a duplicate column if you dropped the table. It looks like your migrations still need some fixing to remove the duplicate.