# Sqlite change data type in android

Tags: android, sqlite, alter-table

Could anybody tell me how I can change the datatype in SQLite from android?

For example, I want to change `varchar(2000)` of a column `diary_content` in table `diary` to `TEXT`. How it is possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083543/modify-a-columns-type-in-sqlite3

Comment: `varchar(2000)` and `TEXT` have exactly the same [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), so you do not need to change the table at all.

Comment: Hi ok so you think if i go over 2000 chars and want to save the text it will still work too ?

Answer (score 0):

**Trick that might solve your issue**,

You can try something like

### Ex:

To change the datatype of the last_name field to VARCHAR, could do the following:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE employees RENAME TO _employees_old;

CREATE TABLE employees
( employee_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR,
  hire_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO employees (employee_id, last_name, first_name, hire_date)
  SELECT employee_id, last_name, first_name, hire_date
  FROM _employees_old;

COMMIT;

PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
```

Rename existing employees table to _employees_old. Then it will create the new employees table with the last_name field defined as a VARCHAR datatype. Then it will insert all of the data from the _employees_old table into the employees table.

Check [SQLite](http://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/tables/alter_table.php) for more details.

Comment: OK thanx ...have to make some brainstorming about this :) I think you have to be sure 100 % in advance which data type you want to choose in sqlite before  !  Seems not to be very easy to change it afterwards